# firefox plugin inorder to get the data from textbox

Tags: javascript

my problem is that, i what to develop a firefox plugin that extract data from the textbox and it has to be stored in some temporary memory.
i didn't have any idea about plugin's So please give the solution in a detailed manner

thank u.......!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the [extension documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions), and then asking specific questions about things you still don't understand. It sounds like you are asking someone to write the whole extension for you, which isn't really the purpose of SO.

You could also look for open-source extensions that interact with text fields (like one of the ones that allows editing a text field in an external editor) and see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the "It's all text" plugin? It allows you to edit a textarea in your editor of choice. After saving, the textarea is updated.  I'm sure there's some code in that plugin that you could use.

Also, what you're describing sounds really simple.  Are you sure a plugin is the right solution?  Maybe a Greasemonkey script would be easier.